# gdata youtube api 302 'The document has moved'

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I'm trying to get YouTube feeds with the python gdata library.
Authentication features work ok, yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin() works, generating subauth token works, etc., but when I try to get some feeds (GetMostRecentVideoFeed, GetYouTubeVideoEntry, even GetFeed, and any other) I get:

```
RequestError: {'status': 302, 'body': '<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">\n<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>302 Moved</H1>\nThe document has moved\n<A HREF="http://www.google.com">here</A>.\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n', 'reason': 'Redirect received, but redirects_remaining <= 0'}
```

302 to 'google.com'???

I've even tried to do something from the google online tutorials and I get the same error. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

You need to add ssl=False to the YouTubeService object. Don't see nothing about it in the docs though.

```
yt = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt.ssl = False
```